# Override text property of textbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How do I override the text property in a textbox in [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)?

I want this code in WPF:

```
 public override string Text
 {
        get { return Text.Replace(",", ""); }
        set { Text = value; }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are data binding against the TextBox.Text property then another possible approach is to move the logic away from the control itself and place it in a converter. Your converter would look something like this...

```
public class CommaReplaceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString().Replace(",", "");
    }
}
```

And data binding something like this...

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding XXX, Converter={StaticResource CRC}" />
```

...where the static resource is defined as...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CommaReplaceConverter x:Key="CRC"/>
</Windows.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

Text is a dependency property. If you have derived a class from TextBox then you need to override the metadata and provide your validation callbacks

See

- http://blog.ningzhang.org/2008/11/dependencyproperty-validation-coercion.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx#Validation_Callbacks

Answer (score 0):

While the upvoted answers are correct, there is a much simpler approach: as the Text property of  TextBox is bound to a property of an underlying class (usually in the Viewmodel) simply take care to provide the replacement in the underlying class.

Answer (score -1):

You were just missing the text argument?

```
public override string Text 
    { 
        get { return Text.Replace(",", Text); } 
        set { Text = value; } 
    }
```

Comment: no , i want override text property but in wpf don't use this way.